# Not the outcome i need... round of floor?

Tags: php

I Need te have an outcome on 7.33 of
1x5euro
1x2euro
1x20Cent
1x10cent
1x5cent

Now the code is putting out al the cents....(So the 1x1cent en 1x2cent)

What am i doing wrong in it? Using floor or round somewhere?

```
<?PHP
define("EUROS", [50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1]);
define("CENTEN", [50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1]);
$input = floatval($argv[1]);
input($input);
$euros = floor($input);
euros($euros);
$centen = ($input - $euros) * 100;
centen($centen);
function input($input)
{
    if (!isset($input)) {
            exit('Geen wisselgeld :)');
} else {
    $input = floatval($input);
    return $input;
}
}
function euros($euros)
{
    if ($euros > 0) {
        foreach (EUROS as $euro) {
            $euros = round($euros, 2);
            $aantaleuro = floor($euros / $euro);
            if ($aantaleuro > 0) {
                echo "$aantaleuro x $euro euro" . PHP_EOL;
            }
            $euros = $euros % $euro;
        }
    }
}
function centen($centen) 
{
    if ($centen > 0) {
        foreach (CENTEN as $cent) {
            $centen = round($centen, 2);
            $aantalcenten = floor($centen / $cent);
            afrondennaarvijf($centen);
            if ($aantalcenten > 0) {
                echo "$aantalcenten x $cent cent" . PHP_EOL;
            }
            $centen = $centen % $cent;
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Geen wisselgeld :)' . PHP_EOL;
    }    
}
function afrondennaarvijf($centen)
{
    return round($centen / 5) * 5;
}
```

Comment: I would recommend learning the [basics of debugging](http://www.phpknowhow.com/basics/basic-debugging/).

Comment: One thing though: your `afrondennaarvijf` function returns the value, but you never assign it to a variable so it's not actually being used.

Comment: Will do, but can you help me to change te outcome? @El_Vanja

Comment: Well, it seems to me that this function is in charge of rounding the cents up to 5 (instead of using 1 and 2), so why don't you fix that first and then check the outcome?